# CRC bit-order confusion

Tags: c, language-agnostic, crc

I'm calculating a CCITT CRC-16 bit by bit. I do this that way because it's a prototype that later should be ported to VHDL and end up in hardware to check a serial bit-stream.

On the net I found a single bit CRC-16 update step code. Wrote a test-program and it works. Except for one strange thing: I have to feed the bits of a byte from lowest to highest bit. If I do it this way, I get correct results.

In the CCITT definition of CRC-16 the bits should be feed highest bit to lowest bit though. The data-stream that I want to calculate the CRC from comes in this format as well, so my current code is kind of useless for me.

I'm confused. I would have not expected that feeding the bits the wrong way around could work at all.

**Question: Why is it possible that a CRC can be written to take the data in two different bit-orders, and how do I transform my single bit update code that it accepts the data MSB first?**

For reference, here is the relevant code. Initialization and the final check have been removed to keep the example short:

```
typedef unsigned char bit;

void update_crc_single_bit (bit * crc, bit data)
{
  // update CRC for a single bit:
  bit temp[16];
  int i;

  temp[0] = data ^ crc[15]; 
  temp[1] = crc[0]; 
  temp[2] = crc[1]; 
  temp[3] = crc[2]; 
  temp[4] = crc[3]; 
  temp[5] = data ^ crc[4] ^ crc[15]; 
  temp[6] = crc[5]; 
  temp[7] = crc[6]; 
  temp[8] = crc[7]; 
  temp[9] = crc[8]; 
  temp[10] = crc[9]; 
  temp[11] = crc[10]; 
  temp[12] = data ^ crc[11] ^ crc[15]; 
  temp[13] = crc[12]; 
  temp[14] = crc[13]; 
  temp[15] = crc[14];

  for (i=0; i<16; i++)
    crc[i] = temp[i];
}

void update_crc_byte (bit * crc, unsigned char data)
{
  int j;
  // calculate CRC lowest bit first
  for (j=0; j<8; j++)
  {
    bit b = (data>>j)&1;
    update_crc_single_bit(crc, b);
  }
}
```

Edit: Since there is some confusion here: I have to compute the CRC bit by bit, and for each byte MSB first. I can't simply store the bits because the code shown above is a prototype for something that will end up in hardware (without memory).

The code shown above generates the correct result if I feed in a bit-stream in the following order (shown is the index of the received bit. Each byte gets transmitted MSB first):

```
|- first byte -|-   second byte     -|-  third byte 
7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,....
```

I need the single update loop to be transformed that it generates the same CRC using natural order (e.g. as received):

```
|- first byte -|-   second byte     -|-  third byte 
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,....
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking.  If you want to have it run in the other direction, simply switch the direction of the loop over bits.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I could do this in C, sure, but I can't do this later in hardware because I have no way to store the bits while I receive them..

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow!  You're saying that the above code operates in the opposite direction to what you want?  (i.e. it doesn't match the on-the-wire order?)  If so, then simply flip the order in the code so that it does match.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I added some more information, hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: The question is to much hardware related. The Stack-overflow crowd simply does not understand what I'm asking. I'll try my luck at news://comp.dsp instead.

Comment: Dude, seriously, if you're currently having to provide bits in MSB order, then simply flip the loop order: http://ideone.com/4yE2qu.  If that's not what you're talking about, then it's not because no-one understands hardware (I do), but because you're not explaining the problem sufficiently...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [RevEng 16-bit CRC Catalogue](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat-bits.16), you see that there are two different CRCs called "CCITT", one of which is labeled there "CCITT-False".  Somewhere along the way someone got confused about what the CCITT 16-bit CRC was, and that confusion was propagated widely.  The two CRCs are described thusly, with the first one (KERMIT) being the true CCITT CRC:

```
KERMIT

width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0x0000 refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0000 check=0x2189 name="KERMIT"
```

and

```
CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE

width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0xffff refin=false refout=false xorout=0x0000 check=0x29b1 name="CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE"
```

You will note that the real one is reflected, and the false one is not, and there is another difference in the initialization.  In reflected CRCs, the lowest bit of the data is processed first, so it appears that you are trying to compute the true CCITT CRC.

When the CRC is reflected, so is the order of the bits in the polynomial that is exclusive-ored into the register, so 0x1021 becomes 0x8408.  Here is a simple C implementation that you can check against:

```
#include <stddef.h>

#define POLY 0x8408

unsigned crc16_ccitt(unsigned crc, unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    int k;

    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *buf++;
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

I don't know what you mean by "In the CCITT definition of CRC-16 the bits should be feed highest bit to lowest bit though".  What definition are you referring to?

In [this Altera document](http://www.altera.com/literature/an/an049_01.pdf), you can see the shift register implementation of the CRC for a hardware implementation.  Here is a copy of the diagram:

[image: CCITT CRC shift register with taps at register 16, 10, and 3]

For your code, you need to reverse your register, `temp[]`, indices.  `temp[0]` is `temp[15]` and so on.

Comment: Note that the Altera document LFSR shifts to the right, but the LSB of the LFSR (XOR0) is on the left and the MSB of the LFSR (XOR16) is on the right (below register 0). It is not clear if Data In is MSB first or LSB first.

Comment: Yes, it's not clear from the diagram since the data in is just a wire, but the data in is least significant bit first.

Comment: You can see that the schematic implements the same thing as my C code, with the exclusive-or's at bits 15, 10, and 3, which is the hex constant 0x8408.

Comment: The next question is how CRC is appended to the data (MSB first or LSB first)? If I use the CRC calculator linked to by RevEng, a hex input of 0x80 results in a CRC value of hex 0884, which is is 8408 swapped.

Comment: The original post asks to implement a CRC that takes in data MSB first, and since CRC is linear mapping (like a matrix multiply using 1 bit values and xor instead of add), it could be done, but I'm thinking this would be complicated.

Comment: The CRC is sent least significant bit first.

Comment: The online CRC calculator is wrong, or at least misleading.  The CRC16-CCITT of 0x80 is 0x8408.

Comment: The original post is incorrect in the assertion "the CCITT definition of CRC-16 the bits should be feed highest bit to lowest bit".

Answer (score 0):

Update - If you look at:

[RevEng 16-bit CRC Catalogue](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat-bits.16)

there's a link to:

[Online CRC calculator](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html)

The first three labeled as CRC-CCITT operate on data sent or received MSB to LSB using the polynomial 0x11021. The only difference is the starting value:

CRC-CCITT (XModem) - crc initialized to 0x0000, same as prefixing by 0x0000.

CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) - crc initialized to 0xFFFF, same as prefixing by 0x84CF.

CRC-CCITT (0x1D0F) - crc initialized to 0x1D0F, same as prefixing by 0xFFFF.

So my guess is that you want to use one of these three.

Comment: CCITT aka ITU-T includes many standards, including multiple standards for CRC-16 - CCITT: [wiki crc standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Standards_and_common_use) .  So getting back to the original post, it would help if you had an example input and the generated CRC, so which version of CRC-16 - CCITT can be determined.

Answer (score 0):

normally, bits are transferred on the line least significant bit first.  So, in case you have an array of bytes, first bit is least significant bit of first byte, then comes the next to least significant bit... so up to the most significant bit of the first byte and then comes the least significant bit of the next byte.  This is the order of the bits (coefficients) in the polyonomial division you are making.  Try my routines at https://github.com/mojadita/crc.git (you have there a table for CRC16-CCITT)

Comment: This is wrong. RS232 transmits LSB first. I²C transmits MSB first. I²S (serial audio codec format) transmits MSB first. SPI gives a choice, but mostly it is MSB fist.

Comment: CAN bus (the stuff in your car) does MSB first. USB does LSB first. I don't think there is a clear 'normally bits are transferred LSB first'. It depends on the interface.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck yes... ethernet, serial rs232, rs422, hdlc, bisync, token ring and others do LSB first.  There is a historical clear asymetry in that, perhaps originated in the old hardware used to do it.  I have not said every byte in the world is transmitted LSB, just accounted for many protocols that do it LSB. I'm not going to enter in this flame, and don't think this is a valid reason to downvote me.  The library I have given is valid for LSB transmission, perhaps you can propose another that does MSB and we are complete.  Thanks either case.